# Is this FA really equivalent to the given regular expression?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

[image]

From the picture, the automata can accept $(\text L|\text D)^*$ following say $\_\text L\text D$, but in the formula above $(\text L|\text D)^*$ can't follow the $\_\text L\text D$.

So the Automata in the picture is not equivalent to the RE?

Comment: $(L|D)^+ \equiv (L|D)(L|D)^\ast$, hence after a word in $\_(L|D)$ there can be arbitrary many words matching $(L|D)$.

Comment: @ttnick: Thank you!

Comment: @ttnick answers in answers, not comments, please

Answer (score 0):

They aren't equivalent. For example, the string "L__L" is described by the expression, but not accepted by the automaton (no way to have two '_' in a row).

Comment: The expression does not allow two consecutive "_". Perhaps you misread a plus as a kleene star?